# Tensorflow Pandas_input_fn slow, starving CPU/GPU

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I am working on a wide and deep model following the framework in the Tensorflow Wide and Deep tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep). Model works fine when built the old way (load entire dataset from pandas, convert to tensors, feed in input_fn) which is ok for running on a CPU. However, to make it work on the GPU the dataset is too large to fit into GPU memory, so batching is necessary.

I tried using the pandas_input_fn to batch data to the video card and noticed I get spikes of activity followed by long lulls while the next batch is prepared. The odd thing is, this happens even if I run it on a machine with CPU only. The lulls are almost the exact same length, so it isn't simply the video card crushing through a simple model faster than the proc can deliver it. It seems like it is always waiting to begin loading the next batch until the last one is done training. I increased the complexity of the model to make sure it wasn't too easy to compute and still have the same issue. I have tried increasing the number of threads allocated to pandas_input_fn, I have tried increasing the queue size to far larger than seems reasonable (10x dataset size) which helps a bit, but not much. I am not sure if the slowdown is when it is queueing or de-queueing, but I have been unable to solve the issue after a week of troubleshooting.

The data I am working with is 117 columns, 400k rows. I have created a generic script that generates fake values to simulate the problem. However, there are far fewer fake columns than real ones, so the gap between steps is not nearly as long, but still noticeable.
Code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging
import time
import datetime
import tempfile
from math import log2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import monitors as monitor_lib


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.INFO, filename='Classifier.log', filemode='a')
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
logging.debug('Main method started')
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
start_time = time.perf_counter()
logging.info(datetime.datetime.today())

#  sess = tf.Session()

model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

LABEL_COLUMN = "t"

CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ["f", "g", "h", "i"]

ALL_COLUMNS = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "u", "v", "x", "y", "z"]

full_set = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "u", "v", "x", "y", "z", "t"]


model_type = ""

def input_fn(num_epochs=None, shuffle=False):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1,size=(400000, 25)), columns=full_set)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df[CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS].round(0)
    dfindex = df.index    
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.reindex(range(len(df)))
    df.loc[:,CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS] = df.loc[:,CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS].astype(int)
    df.loc[:,CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS] = df.loc[:,CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS].astype(float)
    with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
        return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
                x=df[ALL_COLUMNS],
            y=df[LABEL_COLUMN],
            batch_size=100000,
            num_epochs=num_epochs,
            shuffle=shuffle,
            num_threads=4,
            queue_capacity=400000,
            target_column=LABEL_COLUMN)

def evaluation_input_fn(num_epochs=None, shuffle=False):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1,size=(200000, 25)), columns=full_set)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df[CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS].round(0)
    dfindex = df.index    
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.reindex(range(len(df)))
    df.loc[:,CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS] = df.loc[:,CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS].astype(int)
    df.loc[:,CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS] = df.loc[:,CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS].astype(float)

    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
            x=df.loc[:, ALL_COLUMNS],
            y=df.loc[:, LABEL_COLUMN],
            batch_size=200000,
            num_epochs=num_epochs,
            shuffle=shuffle,
            num_threads=1,
            target_column=LABEL_COLUMN)

def classifier(model_dir):
    with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
        logging.info('Parsing continuous columns into tensors')
        with tf.variable_scope("Continuous_Features") as scope:
            continuous_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS]

        logging.info('Parsing categorical columns into tensors')
        with tf.variable_scope("Categorical_Features") as scope:
            categorical_columns = [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(k, hash_bucket_size=1000, dtype=tf.int32) for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS]

        embedded_columns = []
        logging.info('Creating embedded columns')
        with tf.variable_scope("Embedded_Columns") as scope:
            for i in range(len(categorical_columns)):
                embedded_columns.append(tf.feature_column.embedding_column(categorical_columns[i], dimension=8))

        logging.info('Bucketizing age')
        categorical_columns.append(tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(continuous_columns[0], boundaries=[18, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75]))

        logging.info('Creating crossed columns')
        crossed_columns = [tf.feature_column.crossed_column(["a", "b"],
                                                             hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)),
                           tf.feature_column.crossed_column(["a", "c"],
                                                             hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)),
                           tf.feature_column.crossed_column(["a", "g"],
                                                             hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)),
                           tf.feature_column.crossed_column(["b", "n"],
                                                             hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)),
                           tf.feature_column.crossed_column(["m", "v"],
                                                             hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)),
                           tf.feature_column.crossed_column(["a", "m", "v"],
                                                             hash_bucket_size=int(1e6))]

        wide_columns = categorical_columns + crossed_columns

        deep_columns = continuous_columns + embedded_columns

    logging.info('Creating Classifier')
    with tf.variable_scope('Wide_and_Deep') as scope:
            clf = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
                                                               dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
                                                               dnn_hidden_units=[400, 200, 300],
                                                               n_classes=2,
                                                               config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(log_device_placement=True,
                                                                                                  save_summary_steps=100,
                                                                                                  save_checkpoints_steps=100,
                                                                                                  keep_checkpoint_max=5,
                                                                                                  model_dir=model_dir,
                                                                                                  num_cores=0,
                                                                                                  gpu_memory_fraction=1,
                                                                                                  tf_random_seed=3))

    return clf


def build_model(model_dir, train_steps):
    model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp() if not model_dir else model_dir
    logging.info('Declaring and training classifier')
    clf = classifier(model_dir=model_dir)    
    clf.train(input_fn=input_fn(), max_steps=train_steps) #  , max_steps=2000, monitors=[validation_monitor], hooks=hook
    logging.info('Starting model evaluation')
    results = clf.evaluate(input_fn=evaluation_input_fn(), steps=1)
    logging.debug(results)
    for i in results:
        print(i, results[i])

    return clf


def main():
    config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                            log_device_placement=True)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    build_model(model_dir='C://TFLogs//DWDevGPU', train_steps=20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would really like some help figuring out how to batch tabular (in sql) data to the CPU/GPU fast enough to keep up with compute. It doesn't have to be pandas or numpy, I'll take anything reasonable. So far I have not tried serializing to tfrecord because it seems silly to think that reading from disc will be faster than reading from memory, but I'll try anything. Thank you ahead of time for the help.